# How to make 0 not to evaluate as false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

`this.startOffset` and `this.endOffset` in the following code are values I'm using to select individual characters within nodes:

```
this.startOffset = this.node.length - 1 ||
  this.node.firstChild.length - 1 ||
  this.node.childNodes.item(0).length - 1 ||
  this.node.childNodes.item(0).firstChild.length - 1

this.endOffset = this.node.length ||
  this.node.firstChild.length ||
  this.node.childNodes.item(0).firstChild.length
```

I'm using `-1` in `this.startOffset` because that's the value at the beginning of a character. (e.g. `0,1` will select the first character in the node.)

However, because `this.node.childNodes.item(0).length - 1` will become 0 in the first character, it will return `false` instead of `0` and the code will reach `this.node.childNodes.item(0).firstChild.length - 1`, causing an error.

How can I make it so that `0` doesn't return false, and instead sets `this.startOffset` to `0`?

Comment: will it not be cleaner to just remove `-1` from the condition?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript should help

Comment: @gurvinder372 You mean to place it somewhere else?

Comment: I mean using `children` instead of `childNodes` since `children` doesn't return text nodes.

Comment: Downvoting because the code is overly complex and if it was properly structured the question wouldn't be necessary in the first place.

Comment: *"How can I make it so that 0 doesn't return false, and instead sets this.startOffset to 0?"* The code presented in your first code block will only set `startOffset` to a number, not `false`, provided those `length` properties are all numbers. It will be the first of those numbers that isn't `0`, or `0` if they all are.

Comment: I don't get why are you using boolean conditions to set an integer value, but you could simply add a `(condition) ? 1 : 0` at the end, or use `+(condition)`, or `(condition) | 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ternary operator to return whatever you want as a value

```
this.startOffset = (condition) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If text node is a concern then, try using children instead

```
this.startOffset = this.children.length ||
  this.children.item(0).children.length;
```

This will skip text nodes and return boolean based on whether or not child-node and its child-nodes are present.